# Как пишутся автобусные маршруты?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, названия

Как известно, направления пишутся без кавычек через тире (поезд Москва — Санкт-Петербург). А если речь об автобусных маршрутах, нужны кавычки или нет?
Вижу в СМИ в кавычках: *маршрут № 14 «ст. Химки — ул. Заводская — Вашутино — Ивакино».* Это верно или нет?